# android: getting contact photo is not working, tried many things but still not working

Tags: android

In android i am trying to get contact data, i got success for number but for contact photo i am facing problem. i got contact photo uri `content://com.android.contacts/data/6376/photo` but when i am setting it to image view, the image view will blank

```
/*getting activity result */
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // return from file upload
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String contactID="";
                if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                    try {
                        c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
                                //ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.p
                            }, null, null, null);

                        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                            String number = c.getString(0);
                            int type = c.getInt(1);
                            contactID = c.getString(2);

                            Bitmap photoBitmap = null;
                            Uri photo=null;
                            try {
                                photo = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
                                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                                imageView.setImageURI(photo);

//                              ImageView profile  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);                 
//                              Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactID);
//                              InputStream photo_stream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(), my_contact_Uri);            
//                              BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
//                              Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
//                              profile.setImageBitmap(my_btmp);  
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex((ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                            showSelectedNumber(type, number,contactID,photo.toString());

                        }




//                           Bitmap photo = null;
//                    
//                           try {
//                               
//                               InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
//                                      ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));
//                              
//                              
//                    
//                               if (inputStream != null) {
//                                   photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
//                                   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
//                                   imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
//                               }
//                    
//                               assert inputStream != null;
//                               inputStream.close();
//                    
//                           } catch (IOException e) {
//                               e.printStackTrace();
//                           }


                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Log.w(TAG,e+"");

                            } finally {
                                if (c != null) {
                                    c.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from add contact: "
                            + resultCode);
                }
            }
    }
```

in above code i have tried many things, like input stream etc. but still not getting photo of the contact but successful to get photo path.

When i am going to set data on image view it is not showing any thing on it.

Comment: Check out my answer and try accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the path, you could try this:

```
private void previewImage(String path) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5; // setting the photo quality
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving thumbnail Image follow this code ..

```
 public InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
     Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
     Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
          new String[] {Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
     if (cursor == null) {
         return null;
     }
     try {
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
             if (data != null) {
                 return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
             }
         }
     } finally {
         cursor.close();
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: i tried your code, but not working it. Contacts.Photo.PHOTO is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code it will help you get contact number and its id and from that id number  its will fetch the contact number.

```
public class DemoContact extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = DemoContact.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS = 1;
    private Uri uriContact;
    private String contactID, contactName; // contacts unique ID
    private TextView m_contactName;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
           m_contactName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
    }

    public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {

        // using native contacts selection
        // Intent.ACTION_PICK = Pick an item from the data, returning what was
        // selected.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI),
                REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
            uriContact = data.getData();
            retrieveContactNumber();
            retrieveContactPhoto();
              m_contactName.setText("Contact Name: "+contactName);

        }
    }
    //Retrieve the Contact photo based on the contactId  
    private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

        Bitmap photo = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts
                    .openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                            ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                    new Long(contactID)));

            if (inputStream != null) {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            assert inputStream != null;
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
     //Get the contact number of the selected contact.
    private void retrieveContactNumber() {

        String contactNumber = null;

        // getting contacts ID
        Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME  }, null, null,
                null);

        if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

            contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                contactName = cursorID.getString(cursorID               .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        cursorID.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

        // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
        Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },

                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = "
                        + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

                new String[] { contactID }, null);

        if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
            contactNumber = cursorPhone
                    .getString(cursorPhone
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        cursorPhone.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
    }
}
```

**OutPut:**

[image]